# Using a macro to insert more macros

Tags: python, excel, vba

I've got some Python code that runs a query on a database that is read-only from my end and, which dumps me an Excel spreadsheet with relevant data that I want for visualization. I have several macros which process the data, create and edit graphs, and let me "filter" a couple different ways (each "filter" is several normal filters - convenient compared to manually selecting/clearing multiple filters).

My Python code generates a new Excel file daily stamped with the date. I would like to insert my suite of macros and run the setup ones automatically on each new file, rather than manually importing and executing them.

Is there a way to use a macro to insert several other macros, run some of them, and insert macro buttons or a dropdown box to run the filtering bit? If not, can it be done (or should it be done) from the Python side when it generates my Excel files?

Edit:
The python code was written by somebody else, and I do not know Python. It prints the data using:

```py
    with pd.ExcelWriter(filename) as writer:
        df_merged_final.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Final Data', index=False)
```

Comment: Could you just not use Python to directly do the work of the macros? You can manipulate Excel with Python just as you could with VBA.

Comment: That's probably the better way to do it (except for the filtering). However, I do not know Python - somebody else built the query, and I do not have access to them anymore.

Comment: How exactly is the Excel file created?   Can you use a template which already has the macros you need, and make a copy and populate it with your data?

Comment: You're suggesting copying a master file, then transplanting the data from the newly generated file into the copy, thus avoiding the work of inserting the macros? That would save part of the time/trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all your macros in a .bas file and import that whenever needed.

1) collect all your regular macros and put them in a module. You can even write one parent macro that calls all the other child macros, but they all need to be in this module;

2) export the module as a .bas file;

Then whenever you need the macros:

3) import the .bas file to your workbook;

4) your macros are now available in the ribbon of the developer tab which presents them as a dropdown list. If you used a parent macro, you can just click the parent macro to fire all the child macros.

This allows you to work in the source file itself and you can avoid copying large amounts of data to the clipboard. Also serves as a great backup of your most-used macros in case your master Excel file becomes corrupt.